# Prove that $x=0$ is the only solution in $[0,1]$ for: $x=\int_{0}^{x^2} f(t)dt$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ that $f(x)\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$  for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Prove that $x=0$ is the only solution in $[0,1]$ for:

$x=\int_{0}^{x^2} f(t)dt$.

My attempt:

Let $g(x)=x-\int_{0}^{x^2} f(t)dt$

$g'(x)=1-2xf(x^2)\geq 1-2x*\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2}}\geq0$

So $g$ is an increasing function that $g(0)=0$.

If I knew how to prove that it is strictly increasing, I get that it is positive and that would finish the solution. But i didn't know how to continue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: g'(x) is positive, it's an increasing function.

Comment: @Tuvasbien Your function is not continuous. Continuity at $0$ is the crucial hypothesis here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose $g(c)=0$ for some $c>0$. then $g(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,c]$ so $g'(x)=0$ for all $x \in (0,c)$ which gives $f(x)=\frac   1{2 \sqrt x}$ for all $x \in [0,c]$ . But this contradicts the fact that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Call $w(x) =\int_0^{x^2} f(t) dt$, so that your equation is $x=w(x)$.

Translate your equation into an inequality (I interpret the restriction on $f$ as a strict $<$ requirement and not a $\leq$):

$0 \leq x = w(x) < \int_0^{x^2} 1/(2 \sqrt{t}) dt = |x|$

Hence, the only solution is $x=0$: imagine that there is another solution $x_0>0$, then

$0 \leq x_0 = w(x_0) < |x_0| = x_0$